# What is the name of this puzzle game?

Tags: puzzle-identification

Person A formed 10 small balls of paper (plain white paper, all 10 looked the same). Then person A picked up all 10 paper balls and threw them on a table at the same time. Then you should be able to tell what number between 0, 1, 2, ... and 10 the pattern represents. After everyone gave an answer, person A said the correct number. Then person A picked up all 10 balls of paper again and the next game started.

The table on which the paper balls were thrown was not empty. Everyday things were standing around on the table (bottles, glasses, cutlery, ...). Person A said that everything that is on the table is part of the game and after the 10 small balls of paper have been thrown nothing on the table may be moved. I think that was just for show to mislead the players.

Comment: I remember this game from my childhood. Usually the person throwing the paper balls will place his hands on the table with between 0 and 10 fingers extended. The correct answer is the number of fingers, regardless of what happens on the table.

I do not know the name of the game though, or if it has one. It was just one of several similar "games" where people catch on as you do more and more rounds. Another one in the same vein used a pair of scissors as a distraction when it was really legs crossing that mattered.

Comment: I remember a similar game called "counting horses" where one person claps hands to mimic the sound of running horses and then asks the other person to guess how many horses are there. It turns out that the number of horses is the number of words in the question, e.g. "how many horses?" = 3, "how many?" = 2, "how many horses do you hear?" = 6, etc.